# Setting clang default options?

Tags: c, macos

My copy of clang seems to run with options like `-Wimplicit-int` and `-Wreturn-type` turned on by default.  (Perhaps this is because the language is set to c11 by default.)  I know I can turn these
off using `-Wno-implicit-int` and `-Wno-return-type`, but is there a way to do that by default?  Maybe with an environment variable or rc file?

I'd also like to add a few options, like having it search `/usr/local/include` by default.

I'd also like turn off the `-fcolor-diagnostics`, `-fshow-column`, and `-fno-caret-diagnostics` options, which also seem to be on by default.

(This is clang-600.0.57 / Apple LLVM version 6.0 under MacOS
10.9.5, if it matters.)

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to do this in GCC or clang without re-compiling it.  Also, why would you *ever* want `-Wimplicit-int` off by default?

Comment: Each program [in our case compiler] runs with a default set of options [it has a a standard that it "follows"]. It also offers the possibility to override those defaults (via _cmdline args_, _config files_ or _env vars_) to custom values. Now, I'm not a `clang` expert but if changing its default behavior is not possible (and I think this is OK, from the design PoV), how about creating(this is a workaround:gainarie) a wrapper script (that calls `clang` executable with all of your options)?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I've got gobs of old code that uses old-style idioms ("implicit void" and the like) and clang is the first compiler I've used that complains about any of it.  Over time I can fix it, I suppose, but I'd rather not _have_ to, or all at once.

Comment: [Is there an equivalent to .spec files for Clang/LLVM and where can I find a reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24491386/119527)

Comment: Use a **Makefile**, if you want to make you compiling portable, other users might not want to set the same compiling flags as you, plus it might cause extra undesired output when compiling third party code

Comment: So it appears that the simple answer is "no", and I invite any of you to post that and collect the points or whatever :-). I've downloaded the clang source, but it'll be a while before I'm able to modify it (I haven't even found where it parses the command line yet), so in the meantime, I guess a simple "wrapper" shell script it is: `exec /usr/bin/cc $CCC_DEFAULT "$@"`.

Comment: @dvhh: Makefiles are fine, but in general I like to keep them simple, generic, and portable, so I wouldn't want to clutter them with a bunch of clang-specific personal preference options.

Comment: GCC 5.1.0 uses `-std=gnu11` by default; it will complain about many of the things `clang` is complaining about by default.

Comment: One final comment: Thanks, everybody.  Even though the answer was basically "no", at least now I know that, and can move on. I compile C programs basically every day, so I needed to get this right.  My new wrapper script is working perfectly.  Today's task was to rebuild netpbm, which is now working, succesfully finding headers and libs for jpeg, tiff, png, etc. over in /usr/local. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3038293/105104) you can use the [MAKEFILES](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKEFILES-Variable.html#MAKEFILES-Variable) environment to define extra default target and flags (like a makefile include ), to define the default `CFLAGS` then use `+=`  to add extra param in your project specific `CFLAGS`